# Convert Google Location LatLong integer to floating point

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a tool to convert the JSON provided by Google Location History to a different format, so I can use it with the Leaflet Heat Map Plugin. The problem right now is converting the integers. What I want to achieve is:

```
Positive Longitudes
1717485672 -> 171.7485672
115855930  -> 11.5855930
99811421   -> 9.9811421

Negative Longitudes
-99811421  -> -9.9811421
```

What I tried so far:

```
var longitude = "99811421";
longitude.replace(/(^([2-9]|1[0-9]))/, '$1.');
```

But, this only works for a range from 20000000 to 190000000. That's enough for Germany, but not for the whole world ;)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried with your JavaScript code, also don't forget, you can easily use `parseFloat` or similar functions from JavaScript.

Comment: Are you looking for `x/10000000` ? :P

Comment: Thank you @nisargjhaveri. That would be a nice non-regex solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will "convert" the numbers for you, but in reality all it does is it just divides the number by 10<sup>7</sup>

```
function num(x){ return x/10000000 }
```

Comment: I was so focused on finding the right regex, that I didn't see this simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: Very clever +1. I posted the regex solution and definitely is such a complex one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a regex you can use this one:

```
^(?(?=\d{10}\b)
     (\d{3})|
     (?(?=\d{9}\b)
         (\d{2})|
         (?(?=\d{8}\b)
         (\d{1}))))
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qO4eI7/1)**

[image]

As an explanation this regex is a chain of IF conditionals. In pseudo code is:

```
if match 10 numbers then capture the first 3
else if match 9 numbers then capture the first 2
else if match 8 numbers then capture the first 1
```

Personally, I'd use another solution than a regex but if you want a regex you can go with this approach.

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that this regex has many groups which makes the JavaScript `.replace()` a little tricky. But it certainly works fine for pattern matching.

Comment: @stekhn As you can see in the Substitution section I'm using all the groups together and work for all the cases.

Comment: As awesome this is, I think I'll go for the x/10000000 approach ;)

Comment: @Fede This is about the same as parsing HTML with RegEx. It's possible, but there are better ways ;)

Comment: @DJDavid98 totally I agree. Well, but I like posting regex solutions. I know that many time regex is not a option but I enjoy thinking solutions using regex, it's like a nerd hobby the problem is that sometime community get mad lol